# Is there a way to prevent recent applications from moving to the far left when switching with Command-Tab?

Tags: mac, application-switcher

Given applications ABC; switching to C gives: CAB

Command-Tabbing to an application brings it to the left end of the Command-Tab cycle. Any way to disable this?

Comment: Does it wrap them around or bring it to the left? For example what would it do like this AB(C)D with C activate?

Comment: It brings it to the left: the activated app is brought to the left, so AB(C)D -> CABD

Answer (score 1):

https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/5/applicationswitcher.html

I googled around and found the free Keyboard Maestro software. Using it you can customize your application switcher. You can hide specific applications from appearing in the switcher by going to Keyboard Maestro Preferences -> Excluded. In the switcher, pressing E will toggle hide/unhide apps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.